# mongoose - getting latest records sorted by date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I currently have the following code:

```
var query = ClimateData.find({ device: req.params.device })
                       .sort({datetime: -1})
                       .limit(10)
                       .exec(function(err, data) {
                          res.json(data);
                       });
```

With that being it's possible to get the 10 latest records but starting with the newest.
I actually need the date sorted by date so starting with the oldest of the 10 newest records.

Two `.sort()` calls (as below) did not work. Just got the result that I got 10 records but not the newest.

```
var query = ClimateData.find({ device: req.params.device })
                       .sort({datetime: -1})
                       .limit(10)
                       .sort({datetime: 1})
                       .exec(function(err, data) {
                          res.json(data);
                       });
```

Comment: @turivishal I mean I want to get the 10 records with the newest date. But in the json format I want the result of the query to start with the oldest of those 10. So sorted by date. When using .sort({datetime: 1}) the result is sorted correctly but instead of getting the 10 newest records i get the 10 first in the database.

Comment: Okay two sort can not do this kind of requirement, you have to do that in your programming language (nodejs/js) side. or you can use aggregate() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in find() method,

### Sort in client side after `find()` result:

you can do that in your client side programming language (nodejs), like:

```
var query = ClimateData.find({ device: req.params.device })
.sort({datetime: -1})
.limit(10)
.exec(function(err, data) {
  // SORT FUNCTION
  data.sort((a, b) => a.datetime < b.datetime ? -1 : (a.datetime > b.datetime ? 1 : 0))
  res.json(data);
});
```

### Use `aggregate()`:

or try second option `aggregate()` method,

- `$match` you query condition
- `$sort` by `datetime` in descending order
- `$limit` your documents
- `$sort` by `datetime` in ascending order

```
var query = ClimateData.aggregate([
  { $match: { device: req.params.device } },
  { $sort: { datetime: -1 } },
  { $limit: 10 },
  { $sort: { datetime: 1 } }
]).exec(function(err, data) {
  res.json(data);
});
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4agShZTOcjt)

Comment: Worked for me. Do you know why that can't be done with sort either?

Comment: find will give straight result, it can't modify result multiple time, if you want many operation you have go with aggregation pipeline. that is why they have launched aggregation

Comment: Ahh nice to know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Try like this

```
var query = ClimateData.find({ device: req.params.device })
                       .sort({datetime: -1,_id:1})
                       .limit(10)
                       .exec(function(err, data) {
                          res.json(data);
                       });
```

or below

```
var query = ClimateData.find({ device: req.params.device })
                       .sort({datetime: -1})
                       .limit(10)
                       .sort({_id: 1})
                       .exec(function(err, data) {
                          res.json(data);
                       });
```

Comment: Both did not work. Both resulted in getting the correct records but sorted the wrong way round.

Comment: Try with `{ _id : -1 }`

Comment: Tried that one but some how nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var query = ClimateData.find({ device: req.params.device })
                       .sort([["_id", 1], ["datetime", -1]])
                       .limit(10)
                       .exec(function(err, data) {
                          res.json(data);
                       });
```

Comment: Did not work for me. :/ Resulted in getting the first records but sorted correctly.

Comment: after getting data maybe this can help:
ClimateData.sort(data, {datetime: 1}, function(err, sortedData) { ... })